# Need help in part where fraction is simplified in my Lisp program

Tags: loops, recursion, common-lisp, fractions

I usually ask for help when I absolutely don't understand something.

I was tasked to make a Common Lisp program where it adds 2 fractions inputted as 4 separate numbers (n1 d1 n2 d2) and simplifies it if possible.

My first function does is to add fractions in this manner for the numerator (n1 * d2) + (n2 * d1) and this for the denominator (d1 * d2).

The second function then takes the numerator and denominator from the first function then calculates the gcf from it. In this case, I copied a code from the internet since I have no idea how to implement it.

The third function which I'm currently stuck takes the numerator and denominator that passed through the second function and the gcf then both the numerator and denominator are divided to the gcf until either one of them modulo gcf would no longer be zero.

```
(defun simplify (n d dvs)
  (loop
    (setq n (/ n dvs)
          d (/ d dvs))
    (when (or (/= 0 (mod n dvs))
              (/= 0 (mod d dvs)))
      (setq n n d d)))
  (finalprint n d))
```

Since `(return)` can't return more than 1 value, I tried `(values n d)` but the program would just be stuck without doing anything and the same goes for `(setq n n d d)`. Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: setting `n` to `n` is supposed to do anything? it sets `n` to its value? What would that change?

Comment: `(return (values n d))` returns two values.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```
(defun simplify (n d _gcd)
    (cons (/ n _gcd) (/ d _gcd)))

(defun add (n1 d1 n2 d2) 
    (let ((numerator (+ (* n1 d2) (* n2 d1)))
          (denominator (* d1 d2)))
      (simplify numerator denominator (gcd numerator denominator))))

(write (add 10 20 10 20)) ;;; (1 . 1)
(write (add 1 2 1 4)) ;;; (3 . 4)
(write (add 3 4 3 4)) ;;; (3 . 2)
```

`gcd` is a built-in function in LISP so you don't have to worry too much about that. `let` allows you to name your LISP expressions and then use them in the subsequent expressions. For more information consult [this](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm).

Finally, you just need to divide the numerator and denominator by the gcd only once because of the property that if `gcd(a, b) = d`, then `gcd(a/d, b/d) = 1`. For more information checkout [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Applications).

Comment: This is a good answer, I am just a bit unhappy with the underscore is front of _gcd, you can just name it gcd (?)

Comment: I didn't want to confuse the issue by reusing the name gcd again (since it is also a built-in function). If you feel strongly about it, I can edit it! Thanks

Comment: I think that if someone finds it confusing they probably will ask follow up questions; and if you want to prevent confusion, maybe its just better to tell it explicitly ("here this is a function, and there it is a variable, etc. Lisp-2,..."), instead of using an modified name that is not quite idiomatic. But I am not feeling strongly about this.